# How to do on-chain Integer pattern matching?

Tags: plutus, minting, on-chain, mint

I want to do Integer pattern matching **on-chain** but always get an error:

```
GHC Core to PLC plugin: E042:Error: Unsupported feature: Use of Haskell Integer equality, possibly via the Haskell Eq typeclass Context: Compiling expr...
```

It seems to relate to this piece of code:

```
checkMint :: Integer -> Bool
checkMint (1)  = True
checkMint (-1) = True
checkMint _    = False
```

It seems that it uses the Prelude Integer equality operator instead of `PlutusTx.Prelude`. But how can I change that instead of rewriting the function and make it us `PlutusTx.Prelude (==)` instead?

Comment: Have you tried adding the pragma `{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}` ? This make sure that the standard prelude is not imported. This prevents the use of the Haskell Eq type class instead of the Plutus one.

Comment: Yes, good point. It was indeed the problem of using the standard haskell == pattern match. I resolved it by slightly rewriting this function bc I still need the Haskell Prelude in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with pattern matching on `Integer` types according to Input Output Global. The Plutus compiler will currently reject any pattern matching on `Integer` types.

Therefore the best solution is to adjust the code in the following way:

```
checkMint :: Integer -> Bool
checkMint i
    | i == 1    = True
    | i == -1   = True
    | otherwise = False
```